# Can Visual Studio 2010 automatically copy a compiled file to another directory?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, copy, compilation

I have two projects, one VB6 project which compiles to an EXE and one MSVC++2010 project which compiles to a DLL. The DLL needs to be in the same folder as the EXE file in order to work. Can I have Visual Studio 2010 automatically copy the compiled DLL to the VB6 project folder after a compilation?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The easiest way to set this up is to use a post build event.  These run once a build is successfully completed and has a set of handy macros to make access to common outputs, like compiled files, very easy

For example.  Here are the steps to a compiled DLL / EXE into `c:\temp`

- Right Click on the Project and select "Properties"
- Click on the Build Events Tab
- Add the following line to the "Post-Build" box: `copy "$(TargetPath)" c:\temp`

In the above `$(TargetPath)` is a macro for the primary output of a build task: typically the EXE or DLL file.  If you click on the "Edit Post Build" button, then macros you can see the full list of supported macros.

Comment: To copy multiple files at once: **`xcopy /s /y "c:\source" "d\target"`**. Has difficulties with macros though.

Comment: if your $(TargetPath) has spaces in it you need to use quotes. I just spent 10 minutes figuring this out the hard way. [copy "$(TargetPath)" c:\temp] @JaredPar would you mind updating? editing existing accepted answers that are 99% perfect is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: I had the same issue with not having the quotes.  So i went ahead and edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're asking for [Post Build Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)

An example of what you want to do, I believe, can be found [here](http://eyeung003.blogspot.com/2009/11/visual-studio-post-build-event-to-copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is Project > Configuration Properties > Build Events > Post-Build Event what you are looking for? With a command line of something like `copy <dllpath> <dest>`

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has pre and post build events that you can use to accomplish what you want to do.

just go to Project: "project name" properties you should see a tab named build events. There you should be able to create Macros to do it for you.

Hope this helps.